# Get the hierarchy of a XML element with XPath

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, dom-traversal

I am trying to get the ordered list of the hierarchy of a given element in a "application/xml" response.data document that I parse using a DOM parser in Javascript. So the expression should return the list ['Grand Parent','Parent','Target'] for each A tag that has no A children. So I will get a list of lists where the last element of an inner list would be the deepest (in terms of graph depth) value of <A-title>.
Thanks to @Jack Fleeting I know I can get the targets using the expression xpath below :
`xpath = '//*[local-name()="A"][not(.//*[local-name()="A"])]/*[local-name()="A-title"]'` but I am not sure how to adapt it to get to the hierarchy list.

```
<A>
<A-title>Grand Parent</A-title>
   <A>
   <A-title>Parent</A-title>
      <A>
      <A-title>Target</A-title>
      </A>
   </A>
</A>
```

EDIT :

```
axios.get('WMS_URL').then((r) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser()
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(r.data, 'application/xml')
       let xpath = '//*[local-name()="A"][not(.//*[local-name()="A"])]/*[local-name()="A-title"]'
       let xpath2 = 'ancestor-or-self::A/A-title'
       var targets = dom.evaluate(xpath, dom, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
       var targets2 = dom.evaluate(xpath2, targets, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null)
       Array.from({ length: targets2.snapshotLength }, (_, index) => layerNames.push(targets2.snapshotItem(index).innerHTML))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the XPath `//A[not(A)]/ancestor-or-self::A/A-title` you get with `//A[not(A)]` all `A` elements not having `A` children and the next step navigates to all ancestor or self `A` elements and last to all `A-title` children. Of course in XPath 1 with a single expression you can't construct a list of lists of strings (or elements?) so you would first need to sel3ect `//A[not(A)]` and then from there select the `ancestor-or-self::A/A-title` elements.

Using XPath 3.1, for instance with Saxon JS 2 (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xmlm, https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html), you could construct a sequence of arrays of strings directly e.g.

```
//A[not(A)] ! array { ancestor-or-self::A/A-title/data() }
```

The JavaScript code to evaluate the XPath would be e.g.

```
let result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('parse-xml($xml)//A[not(A)] ! array { ancestor-or-self::A/A-title/data() }', [], { params : { 'xml' : r.data }})
```

With DOM Level 3 XPath 1.0 I think you need a lot of more lines of code:

```
let xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(r.data, 'application/xml');

let leafAElements = xmlDoc.evaluate('//A[not(A)]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < leafAElements.snapshotLength; i++) { 
  let titleEls = xmlDoc.evaluate('ancestor-or-self::A/A-title', leafAElements.snapshotItem(i), null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  let titles = []; 
  for (let j = 0; j < titleEls.snapshotLength; j++) { 
    titles.push(titleEls.snapshotItem(j).textContent); 
  } 
  result.push(titles); 
}
```

Comment: If you use Saxon JS 2 instead of using DOMParser and XPath 1 `evaluate` I would use e.g. `axios.get('WMS_URL').then((r) => { let result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('parse-xml($xml)//A[not(A)] ! array { ancestor-or-self::A/A-title/data() }', [], { params : { 'xml' : r.data }}); })`. The `result` variable inside your `then` handler is then a JavaScript array of arrays of strings with the `A-title` values.